# Why the number is not randomized using Matlab

Tags: matlab, random

I am trying to write a Matlab code to simulate a dice and compute its mean and standard deviation.

The problem is that no matter how many times we run this code, the result of randi(6) keeps the same. It made me crazy.

```
n=20;
m=0;
c=0;

for i=1:10000

    while m<n
    x=randi(6);
    c=c+1;
    m=m+x;
    end

    M(i)=m;
    count(i)=c;
    diff(i)=M(i)-n;
end
```

Comment: What is the output that you are expecting?

Comment: I want diff(i) to be 2.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to **reset** `m` and `c` back to 0 once the `while` loop terminates.  `m` is set to 0 outside of the `for` loop only once, and so when `m` finally surpasses `n`, `m` **never changes**.  As such, simply set `m = 0` in your `for` loop before the `while` loop happens.  You also need to set `c` to 0 because you want to count events each time the `for` loop iterates.

I'm also not sure how you could think that `diff(i) = 2.5` for all `i`.  This difference is a **probabilistic** value. Also, I don't see how you could get a floating point number in the difference because you are generating **integers** and accumulating integers for each trial.  I think you need to examine what this value should be.

So:

```
n=20;
%//m=0;
%//c=0;

for i=1:10000
    m = 0; %// Change here
    c = 0; %// Change here too
    while m<n
    x=randi(6);
    c=c+1;
    m=m+x;
    end

    M(i)=m;
    count(i)=c;
    diff(i)=M(i)-n;
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot to set m back to ZERO at the end of the for. If you want the sequence of randi to change you should take a look at the function "rng".

```
n=20;
m=0;
c=1;

for i=1:100

    while m<n
        x(i, c)=randi(6);
        m=m+x(i,c);
        c=c+1;
    end

    M(i)=m;
    count(i)=c;
    diff(i)=M(i)-n;
    m = 0;
end
```

Comment: yeah, but after I changed that, I still got the same result.

Comment: I added the code, the matrix M contains your values. But I'm not sure your statements count(i) = c and diff(i)=M(i)-n are really doing what you expect them to do...